Problem with Creating Powershell script that works with WSL
I am attempting to create a small PowerShell script to automate starting up my IDE for a particular research project I am working on in my University. Since I have a windows OS, I have to use WSL. The program works up until it gets to WSL.exe line, after which it doesn't seem to execute the rest of the ps commands. Is there a fix for this? It's not the end of the world but I am unsure how to do this; I would imagine there's a relatively simple solution I am overlooking.
Here is the PS1 script I wrote. I execute it through the VSCode IDE, by the way:
Write-Output "start"
Set-Location Desktop
Set-Location Example 
#for anonymity
Set-Location "PASS Code"
Write-Output "before wsl"
wsl.exe
#stops working after this^
Write-Output "after wsl" 
conda activate pass 
Write-Output "after activating conda env"
code .

I tried to look into this elsewhere but couldn't find a particular solution to my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So you want to launch wsl.exe in a separate window?

Just to check, are you saying the Windows VSCode IDE powershell session hangs at the wsl.exe line? Or are you expecting the rest of the script after wsl.exe to run in the wsl session that gets started?

You may be in quiet mode.  Try changing to verbose : wsl.exe --verbose

@mclayton Yeah; I was expecting it to execute wsl.exe (which it does), then change the conda environment and open up a new window. If I go into the VSCode IDE powershell after the script stops doing stuff and input the remaining lines of the script manually, everything works.
